# How is `level` used to generate the confidence interval in geom_smooth?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm having trouble emulating how `stat_smooth` calculates it's confidence interval.

Let's generate some data and a simple model:

```
library(tidyverse)    
# sample data
df = tibble(
  x = runif(10),
  y = x + rnorm(10)*0.2
)

# simple linear model
model = lm(y ~ x, df)
```

Now use `predict()` to generate values and confidence intervals

```
# predict 
df$predicted = predict(
  object = model,
  newdata = df
)

# predict 95% confidence interval
df$CI = predict(
  object = model,
  newdata = df,
  se.fit = TRUE
)$se.fit * qnorm(1 - (1-0.95)/2)
```

**Notice that qnorm is used to expand from standard error to 95% CI**

Plot the data (black dots), geom_smooth (black line + gray ribbon), and the predicted ribbon (red and blue lines).

```
ggplot(df) +
  aes(x = x, y = y) +
  geom_point(size = 2) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", level = 0.95, fullrange = TRUE, color = "black") +
  geom_line(aes(y = predicted + CI), color = "blue") + # upper
  geom_line(aes(y = predicted - CI), color = "red") + # lower
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

The red and blue lines should be the same as the ribbon's edges. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's probably use confidence intervals based on the t-distribution and not the normal distribution...

Comment: Thank you! I replaced `qnorm(...)` with `qt(1 - (1-0.95)/2, nrow(df))`, and it perfectly lines up. If you post as an answer, I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As posted in a comment by @Dason, the answer is that geom_smooth uses a t-distribution, not a normal distribution.

In my original question, replace `qnorm(1 - (1-0.95)/2)` with `qt(1 - (1-0.95)/2, nrow(df))` for the lines to match up.